# Display a copy of a table

Tags: tables

I have a table that shows up earlier in my document and I want to display it again later in my document for reference, but if I just copy and paste the code later down it will label it as "Table 2" and not "Table 1", and this also means I would have to manually make changes to both tables. Is there a way to display a verbatim copy of a table later in a document, including the same reference number, such that when I change the original all of the copies change to match?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! i would not do this. This will make confusion in your  document. is it not sufficient to jut use reference to this table? if you persist,  to have this, try with use  at repeated table `\caption*{Table~\ref{table-1}: caption text}`.

Comment: Hi @Zarko , I'd like to put up a copy of the data in the table for reference because it was last mentioned many pages back. I tried what you suggested and it worked to change the label, so now I just need to figure out how to make the second table change with the first. Thanks!

Comment: store table  as `standalone` file in your working directory (or sub directory)  and include it as `input{filename}` or `\input{<subdirectory name>/filename}`.

Comment: *`Let's consider table~\ref{wombat} on page~\pageref{wombat}`* ... If we people would repreat and repeat and repeat and repeat instead of just looking things up, where would we be today?